# How to display JSON into textbox

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I have a sample JSON file. How should I display this line by line, indention not required, on a textbox? Is it better to make a variable for every field?

```
{
  "basics": {
    "name": "Your first and last name",
    "label": "",
    "picture": "",
    "email": "Your email address",
    "phone": "A phone number, with any formatting you like. E.g. (555) 555-5555.",
    "degree": "",
    "website": "Your website URL",
    "summary": "A one-sentence to one-paragraph overview text. Do not include any line-breaks.",
    "location": {
      "address": "Your street address or mailing address",
      "postalCode": "Your postal code (ZIP in the U.S.)",
      "city": "Your city",
      "countryCode": "Your country (e.g. USA)",
      "region": "Your region (state in the U.S.)"
    },
    "profiles": [
      {
        "network": "A social media or other profile that you would like to include (e.g. LinkedIn, Twitter)",
        "username": "Your username on this network",
        "url": "A URL to your user profile page"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work and why?

Comment: JSON content is just a string so you can just use it to fill the innerText of a textarea or any other html element. But you are actually talking about winforms.. yet the comment is still pretty valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class for the JSON. https://json2csharp.com/

```cs
    public class Basics
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string picture { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string degree { get; set; }
        public string website { get; set; }
        public string summary { get; set; }
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public List<Profile> profiles { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string postalCode { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string countryCode { get; set; }
        public string region { get; set; }
    }

    public class Profile
    {
        public string network { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Basics basics { get; set; }
    }
```

You have to Deserialized the JSON before you can use it.

```cs
    Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse)
```